Missing dependancies error when run node dist/server.js in production with Payload cms
After making a production build and uploaded all the dist, build and .env on remote I try to launch the node dist/server.js command in order to run the node server but I got this error:
staging.arkage.it_uf77x2cbf9@host613:~/arkage-website.staging.arkage.it$ node dist/server.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv'
Require stack:
- /var/www/vhosts/staging.arkage.it/arkage-website.staging.arkage.it/dist/server.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1142:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:983:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1230:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/vhosts/staging.arkage.it/arkage-website.staging.arkage.it/dist/server.js:42:32)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1368:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1426:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1021:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/var/www/vhosts/staging.arkage.it/arkage-website.staging.arkage.it/dist/server.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v21.7.3

How I have to proceed? Anyone as facing the same issue?
